# Update a progressbar while processing a file

Tags: c#, user-interface, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have a fun project I'm currently working on. It is a C# WinForms project. Basically, the use is supposed to load a Visual Studio solution file and then the application parses it: builds objects according to what written in the file and so on (explaining what it does in detail is really irrelevant to the question, so I'll stop here).

I have a main form (`frmMain`) that provides the interface for loading the file, and also has a progressbar (`analyzingProgressBar`) that *is supposed* to show progress on the file parsing, since it takes a few seconds. I have set up a `BackgroundWorker`, but I'm stuck - how can I update the prgressbar according to the actual progress?

My code is:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        toolStripPseudo.Text = String.Empty;
        toolStripPseudo.Spring = true;
    }

    private void openSolutionToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openSolutionDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Solution openSolution = new Solution(openSolutionDialog.FileName);

            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.RunWorkerCompleted);
            worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(this.ProgressChanged);
            worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(this.DoWork);

            // start the worker thread
            worker.RunWorkerAsync(openSolution);
        }
    }

    private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // get a reference to the worker that started this request
        BackgroundWorker workerSender = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        Solution openSolution = e.Argument as Solution;
        openSolution.AnalyzeSolution();

        workerSender.ReportProgress() //What do I do here?
    }

    private void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO add graphics
    }

    public void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        analyzingProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends -- do you mean just reading in a file or parsing some text?

Comment: Parsing. I uses Regex and whatnot to find some keywords and load info from the loaded file into some classes I made.

Comment: Yeah, I just did that - thanks. Still not answering my question, though.

Comment: This method openSolution.AnalyzeSolution(); needs to go inside the DoWork method for starts.  But more importantly, inside your AnalyzeSolution() you need to keep calling ReportProgress on your worker so that the event fires.  Put that somewhere in the loop where you are parsing the file.

Comment: Right, that's about what I thought. But there isn't a single parsing loop: it call a bunch of methods (which call other methods) that create objects, lists of objects and so on - it isn't just a simple loop. Is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, to show how progress is changing, you'd need to have some sort of loop going in your `DoWork` event and then a percentage and/or message back to the UI thread:

```
private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var workerSender = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

    // I know I'm making this up.. I have no idea what your method does/returns
    var filesToAnalyze = ((Solution)e.Argument).AnalyzeSolution();

    for (var i = 0; i < filesToAnalyze.Length; i++)
        workerSender.ReportProgress(0, "Analyzing file #" + i);
}
```

Since you don't have anything to iterate over, but just want to call your single method in a separate, background thread, don't bother reporting progress. Unless you break up that single method call somehow, there's nothing else you can do.

Add a `ProgressBar`, with the `Style` set to "Marquee"; show it before starting the thread and hide it in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event:

```
progressBar.Show();
worker.RunWorkerAsync(openSolution);
...

private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var openSolution = (Solution)e.Argument;

    // Run long method (which can't touch the UI, or it'll throw an exception)
    openSolution.AnalyzeSolution();
}

private void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Hide();  // Hide progress bar when job complete
}
```

---

> *AnalyzeSolution() just calls some (let's say, 5) other methods in a row. Can I do something like adding 20% to the progressbar when each methods completes?*

Yes, but then you'd have to call those 5 methods instead of just calling `AnalyzeSolution()`:

```
private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var workerSender = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
    var openSolution = (Solution)e.Argument;

    openSolution.RunMethodOne();
    workerSender.ReportProgress(20);

    openSolution.RunMethodTwo();
    workerSender.ReportProgress(40);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Also, AnalyzeSolution() just calls some (let's say, 5) other methods in a row. Can I do something like adding 20% to the progressbar when each methods completes? I'm kind of confused by all of these events.